# Firebase Cloud function in expo project

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-functions, react-native-firebase

So I have a cloud function (this is not in the react native app directory yet):

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const firebase_tools = require('firebase-tools');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

admin.initializeApp();


exports.deleteUser = functions
  .runWith({
    timeoutSeconds: 540,
    memory: '2GB'
  })
  .https.onCall((data, context) => {

  const userId = context.auth.uid;
  var promises = [];

  // DELETE DATA
  var paths = ['users/' + userId, 'messages/' + userId, 'chat/' + userId];

  paths.forEach((path) => {
    promises.push(
      recursiveDelete(path).then(  () => {
          return 'success';
        }
      ).catch( (error) => {
        console.log('Error deleting user data: ', error);
      })
    );
  });

  // DELETE FILES
  const bucket = admin.storage().bucket();
  var image_paths = ["avatar/" + userId, "avatar2/" + userId, "avatar3/" + userId];
  image_paths.forEach((path) => {
    promises.push(
      bucket.file(path).delete().then(  () => {
            return 'success';
          }
        ).catch( (error) => {
          console.log('Error deleting user data: ', error);
        })
      );
    });

  // DELETE USER
  promises.push(
    admin.auth().deleteUser(userId)
    .then( () => {
      console.log('Successfully deleted user');
      return true;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log('Error deleting user:', error);
    })
  );

  return Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
    return true;
  }).catch(er => {
      console.error('...', er);
  });
});




function recursiveDelete(path, context) {
    return firebase_tools.firestore
    .delete(path, {
      project: process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT,
      recursive: true,
      yes: true,
      token: functions.config().fb.token
    })
    .then(() => {

      return {
        path: path
      }
    }).catch( (error) => {
      console.log('error: ', error);
      return error;
    });
  }
  // [END recursive_delete_function]
```

This is used for my swift app. How Can I use this for my react native app built with Expo?

I have installed the following `yarn add @react-native-firebase/functions`

I have my firebase.js file set up in the root directory:

```
import * as firebase from "firebase";

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "test",
    authDomain: "test",
    databaseURL: "test",
    projectId: "test",
    storageBucket: "test",
    messagingSenderId: "test",
    appId: "test"
  };

// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export default firebase;
```

I have a button:

```
<Text>Delete Account</Text>
<View>
    <Button
        title="Delete Account"
        color="#F9578E"
        accessibilityLabel="Delete Account"
    />
</View>
```

Which when clicked signs the user out and runs the above cloud function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not versed in react-native and in Expo, but from the `@react-native-firebase/functions` [documentation](https://rnfirebase.io/functions/usage#calling-an-endpoint) it seems that you need to do as follows:

```
import functions from '@react-native-firebase/functions';

function App() {


  useEffect(() => {
    functions()
      .httpsCallable('deleteUser')()
      .then(response => {
        // ....
      });
  }, []);
    
  // ...
}
```

---

You are not passing any data from your app to your Callable Cloud Function, i.e. you are not using the `data` object in your Cloud Function, this is why you need to do `functions().httpsCallable('deleteUser')()`.
If you would need to pass some data, the doc shows an example [here](https://rnfirebase.io/functions/writing-deploying-functions#calling-your-function), passing an object:

```
functions().httpsCallable('listProducts')({
  page: 1,
  limit: 15,
})
```

---

*(This is totally in line with the [Firebase JS SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#call_the_function) way of calling a Callable Cloud Function, this is why I answered to the question, even with a lack of knowledge on react-native and on Expo...)*

Comment: Just had to change the import to 
`import firebase from '../../firebase';
import 'firebase/functions''`